# How to redirect broken link to another page using .htaccess file?

Tags: .htaccess

I have uses google webmaster to know the broken links of my website and it generate some broken links because of I have change my website core to framework in php now I want to fix broken links through .htaccess file. Here is my .htaccess file code but first of all my link look like

```
campuslabs.com/enroll-student.php
```

and now my new link look like

```
campuslabs.com/enroll-student
```

and I am using some .htaccess file code for redirection

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} enroll-\+student.\+php\
RewriteRule (.*) http://campuslabs.com/enroll-student? [R=302,L]
```

when I using this it throw 500 error. So, How can we fix it ?Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: What are the plus characters doing in the `RewriteCond` ?

Comment: Apart from that: if you get an http status 500 then _always_ the first place to look is the http servers error log file. That is where you can _read_ what caused the issue instead of having to _guess_.

Comment: and `enroll-\+student.\+php\` is not a **QueryString**  .